# Devart DotConnect for SQLite 4.2.77 upgrade difficulty with VB existing projects

Tags: vb.net, devart, dotconnect

I have just upgraded to DotConnect for SQLite 4.2.77 from a previous version (sorry, can't remember the version). In VB Express 2010, I have successfully gone through the manual installation of components as described in Help. However, when I open projects previously created, I get dozens of errors listed wherever the DotConnect code is used and I can't get further than the page headed "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:". I also have Visual Studio 2012 for Desktop Applications installed, where I get a similar result. Any ideas as to how I can solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We have answered you at http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=24921 .